# Speed comparison between bitwise operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a question about the number of cycles needed for bitwise operation, or more precisely, the XOR operation. In my program, I have two 1D arrays of uint8_t variable with a fixed size of 8. I want to XOR both arrays and I was wondering what was the most effective way to do so. This is a code summarizing the options I have found :

```
int main() {
    uint8_t tab[4] = {1,0,0,2};
    uint8_t tab2[4] = {2,3,4,1};

    /* First option */

    uint8_t tab3[4] = {tab[0]^tab2[0], tab[1]^tab2[1], tab[2]^tab2[2], tab[3]^tab2[3]};

    /* Second option */

    uint32_t* t = tab; 
    uint32_t* t2 = tab2;

    uint32_t t3 = *t ^ *t2;
    uint8_t* tab4 = &t3;

    /* Comparison */ 

    printf("%d & %d\n", tab3[0], tab4[0]);
    printf("%d & %d\n", tab3[1], tab4[1]);
    printf("%d & %d\n", tab3[2], tab4[2]);
    printf("%d & %d\n", tab3[3], tab4[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the best option from a cycle/byte point of view?

Comment: Second one can easily shoot in the foot if you are not fully aware what you are doing.

Comment: You understand that this particular example isn't relevant on pretty much any processor until your data size gets to by way over 1K (for tiny, 1MHz microprocessors) and 20M for current processors, right?

Comment: 1. Do you truly have to optimize this piece of code? 2. Keep in mind that if you want to switch the type of the array you have to be sure that the data fits into new format.

Comment: The only thing you need to worry about is whether the code gets autovectorized by your compiler.

Comment: Note that if the arrays of `uint8_t` are not aligned properly for use as `uint32_t`, you may get dramatically slower performance using option 2 than you do from option 1.  Or you may get crashes.

Comment: Any half-decent C compiler will take care of it, both versions take zero cycles.  Your code is trivially optimized away, only the printf() statements survive.  Never forget to actually look at the generated code when you have a question like this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In fact, I'm pretty sure about the size of the array and it will have a size of 16 (it's a cryptographic encryption function that encrypt block of fixed size). So my idea was to do this with 2 uint64-t. The code here was just here to illustrate my question.

Comment: It depends on the widest type your processor supports with a profit. Ideally you can go even wider, using vector co-processor lile NEON or AVX/SSE. Using normal ALU, 64-bit width is likely the widest you can do.

Comment: Currently, this is a prototype (sorry I cannot say more about this) so the type of processor I'll use to test and compute the cycle/byte will be a core i7.

Comment: If that's the case, then AVX is the way to go.

Comment: Seems interesting but I'm not pretty sure I can't use it. I'll check tomorrow with my teacher if I'm allowed.

Comment: the dereference will take longer than the operation....

Answer (score 5):

All the basic binary operations—*and*, *or*, *xor*, *not*—execute in one clock cycle (or less) on almost every processor architecture ever since the 1960s.  I say "or less" because the overhead of fetching instructions, tracking ready registers, etc., may put the binary operation time into the noise.

To make the algorithm faster, it would be necessary to study the caching characteristics of the data.

Most any practical algorithm crunching with binary operations will be faster than the associated I/O.  Hashing algorithms (like the [SHA family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm)) are probably the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I well understand what you have written, it means that option 2 with 1 XOR is more efficient than option 1 with 4 XORs. Is that right or am I totally wrong ?

Comment: Since '60s? ... I know it's false! :) The 8088/6 spent 3 cpu cycles to execute a XOR reg,reg :) The 1st Intel CPU that executed a XOR reg,reg in 1 cpu cycle was the 80486.

Comment: You say: "All the basic binary operations—and, or, xor, not—execute in one clock cycle (or less) [...]". How is possible a CPU executes an instruction in less than one cycle? (Maybe only in modern architecture that groups instructions)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini:  Intel has long been an outsider.  The 8086 and 8088 could do nothing in 1 cycle (not even a no op).  Even a register to register move takes 2 clocks.  I agree that NOT, XOR, AND, and OR take 3 clocks, but that is pretty much its maximum speed for anything.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini Multi-issue chips can execute more than one in one cycle, so effectively less one cycle per instruction.

Comment: @Wallik .. You said: "execute in one clock cycle (or less) on **all processors** ever since the **1960s**" XD

Comment: @ user3528438, exactly what I mean with: (Maybe only in modern architecture that groups instructions) ...

Comment: @SergioFormiggini:  Fine.  I have revised my wording.  I could go further with "every sane computer architecture since the 1960s" or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

Single integer operations are usually faster than four single byte operations. For example, memchr() using the single instruction loop: rep scasb ,  which is byte oriented, is slower than an integer optimized version of memchr(), even though it involves about 12 instructions per integer.

Comment: According to what you say, it would be better to use option 2. Is that right ?

Comment: Option 2 should be better, but on such a small amount of data, it would be difficult to measure. If doing this on a large array (1 million bytes or more), then that would be large enough to use a high speed counter (like rdtsc intrinsic, QueryPerformanceCounter, ... ), to compare.

Comment: In fact I have to do this a lot of time but I only put a small part of my program so that everything stays clear.